# Visa Free to Visa D Transition

Tags: visa, schengen

I am a researcher with an American passport and I will be starting a PhD Program in Spain. I have a visa-D but the consulate here issued it with a validity date as my contract start date. Naturally I'd like to arrive early to set up my home and all that. 
Has any one here experienced this? The consulate here says that's how they issue D visas and I should be able to enter visa free, but I'm anxious for the border guard to see my passport with a visa which is not yet valid. Should I enter, exit, and then reenter schengen on the day my visa is valid?

Comment: If you enter visa-free you’ll want to get an exit stamp or other official change of status record to show when the 90/180 day clock that governs your visa-free stay stopped ticking, eg in case you want to visit Schengen countries other than Spain during the validity of the D visa.

Comment: @Traveller that is not necessary under the Schengen codes, but individual countries have different interpretations about it because the codes are actually entirely silent on the matter.  The Schengen codes also have no concept of "status" whatsoever; they only speak of the possession of a valid document of this or that sort. In particular, periods of stay authorized by a D visa don't count, regardless of whether the D visa was in effect on the day of entry. I don't know what Spanish national law has to say on the matter, however.

Comment: Related question from TSE https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88153/how-to-switch-from-tourist-visa-to-resident-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area